# Declarator modifier position in variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Declarators. Yes, declarators. They are the source of a lot of coding convention debates. It's a really good topic for arguments -- C++ doesn't rule which one is better than the other (it doesn't care!). And so we can write these without worrying someone might make fun of you:

```
int x;

int& a = x;
int &b = x;

int* c = &x;
int *d = &x;
```

In syntactical terms, `b` and `d` are "more valid" than the others. We are required to put declarator modifiers before the names:

```
int m, *n;   // m is an int; n is a pointer to int
```

But the tide seems to turned in favor of one. With C++11's variadic templates, the position of declarators seems to be restricted to the form where the modifiers are closer to the base type:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void VariadicFuncRef(const Ts&... args) { }
                             ^
template<typename... Ts>
void VariadicFuncPtr(Ts*... args) { }
                       ^
```

It is an error to write these forms:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void VariadicFuncRef(const Ts... &args) { }

template<typename... Ts>
void VariadicFuncPtr(Ts... *args) { }
```

For a concrete example, click [here](http://ideone.com/KfHC5W).

And so, my question is this:
**Why are we limited to this (the legal) form and can't use the other?**

Any thoughts guys?

**ADDITIONAL 1:** I'm also interested on the design decision on why is this "rule" "enforced".

Comment: @Nawaz It came to me when I spent minutes trying to compile code with the wrong syntax. Lesson learned: never use features you aren't well accustomed with.

Comment: This will restore your world: The three ... are part of the declarator too!

Comment: You can aswell say "The position of the first character of my variable name is restricted to a location closer to the base type". That is IMHO a weird thing to say.

Comment: Perhaps the rationale is because the declarator part too can make use of packs (function or array declarators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would not say that `int &a` is *more valid* than `int& a`. You may say it is more readable, or a good practice, but that is a different thing altogether.

Second, the parameter unpack syntax `T...` can be read as *"the type-pattern on the left side of `...` is expanded, forming same or different actual function parameter types matching the form of the type-pattern"*. So when you write `f(T&...)`, it can be expanded to `f(int&, float&,  double&, Xyz&, Abc&)`. But that doesn't seem to be so obvious (at least to me) when the syntax is `T...&`. So maybe, that is one of the *several other possible* reasons why the Standard made it like that.

Also note that `args` in `T&...args` is *optional*. So if you don't write it, then `void f(T...&)` looks weird (to me, at least) and `void f(T&...)` looks better aesthetically at least.

You could also compare syntaxes like : `T * const & ...` with `T... * const &`. The *type-pattern* is more obvious in the former syntax than in the latter.

Comment: Good point. Alas we could also say that `&args` in `T... &arg` (if this is valid) expands into, like, `int&, float&...`.

Comment: I'm somewhat convinced by your answer. Many thanks. But I could also use third-party opinions. I hope you could afford the wait.

Answer (score 4):

The old declarator syntax was simply one rule with insignificant white space, but your idea is two. I doubt the committee would be in favor of having two rules when one would be sufficient.

The choice of putting the declarator on the left was most likely made for two reasons:

- idiomatic C++ nowadays prefers `int* x` rather than `int *x` (Bjarne uses the former for example). Most consider declarator syntax a mistake.
- Parameter pack expansion expands things to the left of the `...`, not to the right.

Comment: @MarkGarcia `std::forward<Ts>(args)..., args` is expanding the packs to the left of `...`, not the right.

Comment: Alright. That's outright out of my league (`std::forward`). But I'm learning! (No need to elaborate `std::forward`)

Answer (score 2):

> Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.
>
> -- Antoine de Saint-Exupery

The difficulty in programming language design is not to add features, it is to refrain from adding them. Every feature, every variation of syntax, has a cost:

- they must be specifically coded in the compiler
- they pose the risk of introducing bugs
- they pose the risk of interacting badly with another feature/variation
- ...

The syntax in C and C++ is (mostly) whitespace insensitive, therefore it does not matter where you place the `&` or `*` and both preferences can coexist without extra burden; however in the case of variadic templates it does matter because of the `...` token. The comittee thus decided to pick one, and they picked the most idiomatic in C++ (which put emphasis on the full type rather than the base type).